# Java; paint ( Graphics ) called too much after resizing window!

Tags: java, graphics, canvas, resize, paint

I have a question. Recently I was looking into ways to implement hardware rendering using Java. My goal was not to use an external library such as OpenGL. I found a post on a website that detailed how to do so.

This is what the code was (I renamed some items):

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        createVolatileImage();

        do {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = getGraphicsConfiguration();
            Graphics offscreenGraphics = volatileImage.getGraphics();

            int validationCode = volatileImage.validate(gc);
            if (validationCode == VolatileImage.IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE) {
                createVolatileImage();
            }

            offscreenGraphics.setColor(getBackground());
            offscreenGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

            offscreenGraphics.setColor(getForeground());
            paint(offscreenGraphics);

            g.drawImage(volatileImage, 0, 0, this);
        } while (volatileImage.contentsLost());
    }

    private void createVolatileImage() {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = getGraphicsConfiguration();
        volatileImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
```

Unfortunately, if I resize the window - the paint ( Graphics ) method (in the class Canvas) gets called like 1,000 times within a second, causing an OutOfMemoryException.

Has anyone encountered this before?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be wise to call validate() from inside your paint() routine, since validate() can call repaint() which calls paint(), setting up an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an OutOfMemoryException is because you never clean up your `VolatileImage`. The way I see it, you are allocating a new `VolatileImage` every time `paint()` is called, which can happen many hundreds (or in your case over a thousand) times per second. Unless you free the memory used by the `VolatileImage` or fix things so that you make the allocation **once** instead of once per frame, your application's memory space will balloon until you crash the JVM. Try adding a call to `offscreengraphics.dispose()` at the end of your rendering loop. Also read the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html).

EDIT:

Another useful [reference](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Java%3aTutorials%3aVolatileImage).

Comment: Would I dispose before the while ( ... ) or after? Because I have tried before the while ( ... ) and no avail.

Comment: I would think disposing before the while loop would have the desired effect. Perhaps you could post more of your code? It is not uncommon for paint() methods to be called more than 1000 times per second for simple scenes, perhaps the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: I doubt that it lies elsewhere. All that the application is, is just a frame that has a canvas added to it. And the canvas class overrides paint ( ... ) and update ( ... ).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that other "useful reference." This is exactly what I needed. When I get around to rewriting that piece of code, I will definitely utilize that website.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you should have a loop in your paint method. It should paint a single time for each action that needs a paint, then return.When you drag the screen, the OS/env will take care of dispatching repaint messages over and over to your app. You should repaint if possible then just return. No loops checking if content is lost, the OS will tell you when to do your painting.

Comment: In the Javadocs there is the do-while loop, checking if there was contents lost.

Comment: is it inside a component paint method?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html), this is the expected behavior when painting in AWT. In particular, a system-triggered painting operation occurs when a component is resized. As @rjacks notes, you need to `dispose()` any resources created in `paint()`.